# loading image from view controller 1 NSDictionary into detailViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiimage, uitextview, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to use an NSMutableDictionary in a view controller to load an image and text into a detail view controller when an image is tapped.  I am new to programming and I am trying to understand.  Could someone please help.

Here is my code in the view controller 1 .m

```
- (void) coverflowView:(TKCoverflowView*)coverflowView coverAtIndexWasDoubleTapped:(int)index{



    SomeDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[SomeDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

        if ((int)index == 0) {
             NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"0002.jpg", @"imagekey",
                            @"This is #1", @"textkey", nil];

        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey"]);
        }



        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

when I build and run this the image key and text key are called but don't show up in the detail view controller.
my detailViewController.h

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface SomeDetailViewController : UIViewController < UITextViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

    IBOutlet UITextView *myText;
    NSString *imagekey;
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;
    NSString *textkey;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *myText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imagekey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *textkey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;
@end
```

and my detailViewContoller .m

```
@synthesize myDictionary;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageView .image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    self.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey"]]; 

    self.myText.text =[(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey"];
}
```

I know this is similar to another post but I was advise not to use NSUsersDefaults so I am trying this.

There are no errors but nothing shows up

Comment: I found out the answer I just had to add one line of code in my first view controller.   **detailViewController.myDictionary = myDictionary;**  now it works perfectly